# render angular component inside swiper appendSlide()

Tags: angular, typescript, swiper.js

I am trying to load my angular component inside swiper.appendSlide like this

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        type: 'fraction',
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
    swiper.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>')
    swiper.appendSlide('<div class="swiper-slide"><app-Hello-Component></app-Hello-Component></div>')
```

It shows me two slides but second slide is empty and do not render my component **app-Hello-Component**.
What should i do if i want to append slides dynamically with angular components inside swiper-slide?

Comment: @ADDEL, did you come alright with this problem?

Comment: @ADDEL, did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `<div></div>`

Add `<app-Hello-Component></app-Hello-Component>` without surround it by `<div></div>`